# React redirect to index.html, www & https

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a react app published to the web.  I have the solution in place suggested by react to redirect all pages to index.html, that seems to work just fine by itself.  I also need to redirect everything to https://www.  That is where things start to fall apart.  I can find bits and pieces of articles like:
[react-router redirect to index.html AND remove www from url in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396488/react-router-redirect-to-index-html-and-remove-www-from-url-in-htaccess?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

These provide useful info, but I'm still stuck in a position where I'm getting redirect loops in certain situations.  I'm hoping someone with far more superior rewriting skills can point out my errors.  I don't know if it matters, but I am using "react-dom": "^16.3.2", "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2", "webpack": "^4.8.1"

This is what I have come up with:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^. index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: ` I'm getting redirect loops in certain situations`: For what URLs do you get a redirect loop and did you test in a new browser?

Comment: @anubhava I am actually getting a redirect loop on both the www and https.  As is, it's only working with the index.html rule in place.  Once I add the www and https rule, I run into the redirect loop.

Comment: These rules won't cause redirect loop unless there is some other conflicting code/rule .

Answer (score 1):

Some subtle differences that may improve things:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [END]
```

The first change prevents a double-redirect, the patterns are simpler, and, lastly rewriting is terminated asap. If it works, then change your `302`s to `301`s.