# React web app not working on remote server

Tags: reactjs

The app (create react app) build with "npm run build" is working fine on virtual host on macos, but I uploaded to a free server http://app42.42web.io/ and works fine except when you navigate to a route different than home, and reload page, then a 404 from service hosting appears on screen.

Any help

Comment: You need to make all pages render the same HTML file

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can do that?

Comment: No way to tell with the information in the question. Something like `mod_rewrite` for apache or `try-files` for nginx

Comment: ok, solved with mod_rewrite . helpfull answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396488/react-router-redirect-to-index-html-and-remove-www-from-url-in-htaccess